# Control load html with: new Image().src = HTML_URL

Tags: javascript

I am loading in browser cache next page with:

```
new Image().src = 'HTML_URL';
```

How do I control end of loading? If loading NOT an image -- always calling `onerror`.

I can't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onerror` callback.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'HTML_URL';
image.onerror = function () { 
  alert('I failed'); 
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `image.onload = callback`

Comment: if loading NOT_IMAGE (html, etc) calling always only onerror!

Comment: I'm sorry, Dmitry, I'm having a hard time understanding your question. If the url you are trying load as an image is *not* an image, `onerror` will **always** be called. If you are trying to load html, you should look at ajax. Again, apologies for misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Thanks! I have html+css+js = 25-30Kb. But I preload next page (4-5Kb) in cache for gprs connections with Image().src.
Without jQuery (big size), without ajax (big size).